# Why are questions that are too old to migrate being migrated?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, off-topic, old-questions

Coming upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948968/knoppix-cd-booting-tar-extract-error?noredirect=1) I felt that it was off-topic for StackOverflow, so I immediately clicked on `close`.

I was promptly informed that this question was `too old to migrate` so, presumably, I would not be presented with a migration candidate list. I thought that it was alright - quite honestly I felt it was not *spectacular enough* to worry about it.

So I clicked on `off topic` and then on `close`... and the question was promptly [migrated to SU](https://superuser.com/q/525381/55602), presumably because that was the migration target of the previous close votes.

So, if the question can still be migrated, why not show the migration target list? And if the question is in fact too old to migrate, shouldn't that check happen at the actual close time, rather than at the close-vote submission time?

Comment: You should add that it's not right at the 60 day mark either and that this is instead a question that is over 11 months old...

Comment: It seems like it would probably be easy to fix, but how often does (or could) this actually happen? Are there a lot of questions that have four matching migrate votes that are now over the day limit?

Comment: @jmort253, to be honest, since I am not really active in MSO, I was not aware of the actual time limit - just that it existed. I just reported a perceived conflict between presentation and behavior...

Comment: @animuson: I would assume that this would be possible even with three migration votes - isn't closing a majority vote?

Comment: Also, this is an old question. I'd think the votes would have expired by now.

Comment: @thkala: Automatic migration requires a super-majority, aka 4 votes for migration to the same site.

Comment: If they are indeed from right before the SE changes, then this issue should just age away on its own.

Comment: @animuson: that's good to know...

Comment: @jmort253 No, they shouldn't.  Imagine a question that's asked today that gets 4 migration votes, and 1 year from today a 5th offtopic vote is added.  Also, close votes only expire if there are sufficient views of the page over that period of time, if they're aren't, the votes don't expire.

Comment: @jmort253 Close votes only expire if a question gets viewed, that one has only 85 views, afaik expiry needs at least 100. I cast my close vote on 20 January, I guess the other three also came within a few days (slugster's probably on 22nd, since that was the day of his edit). Seems old migration votes beat "too old to migrate".

Comment: @DanielFischer I think (not entirely sure despite [my best attempts to experiment by watching view counters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away)) that the ageing away of close votes has changed with the new review system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you suspected, it had four migration votes that predated the 60-day rule. Since we don't currently convert old migrate votes to plain OT votes after 60 days, it is still possible to get around the restriction in cases where a majority (or 4 votes on SO) recommend migration prior to the 60-day mark.