# Is there a way to see the reviews of a particular question?

Tags: feature-request, support, review, vote-to-close

I voted to close a question I thought was too localized, and four days later I see that my close vote has apparently been aged away.  The question only has <100 views right now, so based on [what Shog said here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/137004), I'm assuming the question was reviewed and people opted to leave it open which then kicked off the close vote aging process.

Is there way for me to see which <strike>morons</strike>fellow users thought that the question deserved to stay open without tediously clicking through the close vote queue history?

---

@Dukeling brings up the important question of motivation for this feature that I didn't address.

1. First and foremost, I just want to be able **to check that the vote-aging system is working correctly** (and/or that I understand correctly how it's working). I was surprised that my vote had aged out on a little-viewed question, I want to confirm that this is due to it having been reviewed.
2. Secondly I want **to make sure the reviewers are working correctly**.  The review queues have had occasional issues with reviewer accuracy. If the particular reviewers seem like reliable folks with a history of correct reviews, I'll assume that I was mistaken about the question and revise my thinking about which questions to close.  If they're all robo-reviewers, I'll flag the question or bring it up on meta to see that it's handled correctly.
3. Finally, philosophically I think that **this information *should* be readily available**. I could find the reviews by going through the entire review history, so it's not private information. Making public information less accessible can have its uses, but the outcome that's likely to ruffle feathers is already public; if reviewers opt to close a question, their names are prominently attached to it.  This feature would be more important when the review decision is "Leave Open" as in this case (apparently).  This might lead to more whining, but it seems like only a slight risk.

Comment: +1, but for different reasons. I'm actually starting to doubt my +1 because I don't agree with your reasons. Firstly, what did you vote? "too localized" isn't an option anymore. Secondly, I don't know whether your close vote was actually valid because you didn't point us to it. Thirdly, for what purpose do you want to see who voted as such? Moderators are supposed to handle such things (although there's probably currently too little accountability for incorrect actions with the current system - but I'd prefer to have this fixed rather than having random users haunt me because of some error).

Comment: @Dukeling Good points about motivation, see update. I purposely left the question out because I didn't want discussion about the general support issue/feature request derailed by specifics about the question/vote.

Comment: I'd like to see this not just for close votes, but for all queues.  I may want to see if there were rejected suggested edits, the state of VLQ flags on posts, who reviewed any first posts, etc.

Comment: Diamond mods do get to see this.

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248286#277352), it is now possible to find reviews from the [timeline of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info). (But only when they're already finished - not ongoing reviews.)

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the privilege to review closed votes, I can only reflect on what I'm able to do/see on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). However, I would assume this to be parallel in nature to what is done on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

If the *fellow users* followed the review process, then yes. These are recorded and visible by clicking on any one of the "review choices" next to the question. For example:

[image]

Clicking the above circled link reveals all those that reviewed the question and their actions:

[image]

So you'll have to find at least/only one review of the post in question to see all the reviews made on it. If they did not follow this procedure (and just closed based on premise), then of course, there won't be a trace of it.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I should've been more clear.  I know how to see the reviews if I'm in the review history, but right now all I have is the question and the suspicion that it's been reviewed.  I could slog through the history to find its entries there, but on StackOverflow that'll be hundreds or thousands of reviews to scan through.  I want to know if there's a shorter route given only the question.

Comment: @blahdiblah: True. [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is small in comparison to [so]. As such, there's not much of a search to find things. Close-votes to date is a whopping 16K and counting! So you're after a "reverse search"... something like `http://stackoverflow.com/q/12345/review` and then see what kind of reviews have been acted upon that question (#12345)?

Comment: Exactly.  The info's all public, just not necessarily easily accessible.

Comment: There should be a checkbox at the bottom of the review history that says "Show only my own reviews (including skipped)" that should, at least, make the list a bit more manageable so you can get back to the review you were looking for.