# Is there any general way to obtain the review ID or review summary for a certain review job without the 10 k tools?

Tags: support, review, user-interface, timeline, review-stats

Accessing the full review history is a privilege for 10 k users but, statistics for individual reviews can be viewed by everybody ([two](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/close/8985) [examples](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/close/18996)).

These review summaries can be somewhat useful for different aspects, such as understanding what happened to a review item that you initiated, e.g., if your close vote remained the only one on a question, you can only guess by the elapsed time whether nobody else has reviewed it or whether the review is finished with everybody disagreeing. Or you can see who performed a disputed review decision and discuss it.

My question now is: **Is there any way to acess these review summaries or obtain the review ID** – which would allow to find these summaries – **for a particular review task?**

I am aware that the above information, in particular the reviewer identity, can be abused and it may therefore be undesirable that everybody can find this information. But then, at least on small sites, it’s quite possible to obtain the review ID from guessing. Also, I can access the review summary for every review that I participated in or even skipped from my review history and the review summary for every successful edit from the edit history.

Comment: If you mean see the review tasks associated with specific question the answer is "no", and it's [already been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204125/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-reviews-of-a-particular-question).

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well, as every review (except for tag-wiki edits) is inevitably associated with a question, this would suffice. However, the linked question is only about close votes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The question you linked to doesn't have a status-declined on it - does that mean it's not necessarily no and just hasn't been answered yet?

Comment: @Tim the "no" was on the current status - currently it's not possible. And indeed, that's not declined so there is still a chance one day in the future this will be done. I posted it mainly so that the OP won't change the question to a feature request, as it would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Links to all completed reviews of a post as well as a bunch of other handy information can now be accessed through the [timeline view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/282094).

#### Historical Information:

In case someone reading this doesn’t know what the timeline view is: It’s one of the hidden ([experimental](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/180594)) features of all Stack Exchange sites. More detailed information about it can be found [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569).

There are many browser extensions simplifying the access to the post's timeline. I use [this one](//stackapps.com/a/4238), but there are at least [two](//stackapps.com/q/2138) [other](//stackapps.com/q/2371) providing the this functionality.

Answer (score 8):

There is a ReviewTasks table in the Data Explorer, which does have a PostId value in it. So I'd assume you could just find all review tasks with the post ID you want them for. The data is just only updated weekly.

[Something simple like this would work.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/271657/354761/get-all-review-tasks-for-a-specific-post-id) Gives you the review ID and what queue it was from. With that information, you could construct the URL manually to access the review item.

```
http://{{site}}/review/{{review-type}}/{{review-id}}
```

Where `{{review-type}}` is one of the following:

- Suggested Edit: `suggested-edits`
- Close Votes: `close`
- Low Quality Posts: `low-quality-posts`
- First Post: `first-posts`
- Late Answer: `late-answers`
- Reopen Vote: `reopen`
- Community Evaluation: `site-eval`
- Triage: `triage`

Comment: I have [here a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366230/find-all-reviews-for-a-post?postid=28254987) that also builds the link to the review item.