# Can moderators get a convenient way to see the review history of a non-completed review task?

Tags: feature-request, review, moderators, review-history

The review history of a post can be accessed [from the post's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277352/643262) or [from the site's review history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204128/643262) if one has the 10K tools. See an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/594603) (where I do not have the 10K tools):

[image: close-vote review history of a question on Math.SE]

However, if the review has not been completed (and I can review), that link brings me to the review task, where I cannot see what review votes were already cast. For example, in [this review link](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/21738), I get:

[image: Low Quality Posts review task on Spanish.SE]

I understand the rationale of hiding the review history of a post from the current reviewer, to prevent the reviewer from being influenced by other users' decisions. However, this rationale does not apply to moderators, who are expected in many communities to not use their review hammer except in flagrant cases. As a moderator, sometimes I am interested in the review history of a post but I do not want to do the review. For example, on Spanish.SE recently there were discussions about why the Low Quality Posts review queue was slow. To contribute to those discussions, I had to manually go to the site's review history and Ctrl-F for the posts that were still in the queue. This is inconvenient and time-consuming. The "show review history" mod link on posts does not help either, as it also brings me to the review task.

**Is there a way (or can we get one) for moderators (and optionally high-rep users) to see the review history of a non-complete review task?**

Comment: I'm not a mod but what did you search for with CTRL+F?

Comment: @rene Let's say I want to see the review history of [that post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/21738). I go to [the site's LQP review history](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) (you probably cannot see it, so here is an [example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history)) and Ctrl-F a part of the title of the question, e.g. "juicioso", to find the lines where that particular post was reviewed.

Comment: A simple workaround: view the review task item while logged out. But that's very tedious.

Comment: I have a userscript for that, at the bottom of this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306412/578411 (keep in mind that /review/history only shows a review once at least one task has been completed. It won't show the full "waiting for a reviewer" queue.