# When does the Community ♦ moderator vote to close a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, community-user, faq-proposed

Occasionally, there are questions for which one of the close voters is the Community ♦ user. When does this happen, and why? What is the difference between this and a deleted user?

For instance, one of the close-voters [on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227974/error-lunching-update-manager) is [Community ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community).

[image: question closed by Community ♦]

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90929/can-i-keep-using-ubuntu-9-04-if-its-outdated) was closed by "Mik" but his profile wasn't linked, which implies the user was deleted.

[image: question closed by Mik]

From [this Meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8176/why-doesnt-the-user-link-appear) it is clear that Mik's profile is now deleted and hence his name is not linked to his profile.

> [Return to FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/206222)

Comment: Wild guess: If the account VTCs. Then gets deleted. Then the question gets closed.

Comment: When high rep user choose to delete his/her account and got lots of activity, sometimes the team will transfer all his votes to the Community account so they are preserved. It's quite a recent thing, so my guess is that such user voted to close and the close vote was transferred along with upvotes and downvotes. :)

Comment: That's not quite how it works, @Shadow. See my answer.

Comment: Do you mind if I hijack this into an faq-proposed question?

Comment: @Emracool Go ahead :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Mysticial got it right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228455/when-does-the-community-moderator-vote-to-close-a-question#comment748995_228455): even though the question was just closed, the vote was cast over a year ago. Close votes are not deleted when the user who cast them is - instead, ownership is given to the Community user.

When a question is closed, the names of the voters who closed it are recorded in the post history. So questions closed after some voters have had their accounts removed will credit Community, while questions closed before voters have their accounts removed will attribute the original voters. This is the difference between the two examples you list.

**Update 9th March 2015**:

From now on, it may also appear that Community has voted to close a question as a duplicate to another. More information can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes); rolling over the Community name will bring a tooltip saying that the OP agreed his/her question is a dupe.

Comment: If two or more closevoters get deleted before the question is closed, will Community be able to vote twice?

Comment: yes, @cheapeffectivedietpills

Comment: It is extremely complicated and most of it went over my head... Can you please clarify the 3rd and 4th paragraphs... Initially you mentioned that it was a Close-"**vote**" (and was cast before June 2013); but in 4th para you mention it as "vote-**flag**"... What was it - a vote or a flag. And are these **flags** treated differently than the "**votes**" cast before June 2013. I am completely confused..

Comment: See edit, @Aditya.

Comment: @Shog9: You cheated there :-) ... I was asking you to clarify things and you removed all those confusing parts instead of clarifying... I had obviously understood the part that "User votes >> Question Closed >> User Removed >> results in name of user shown but not linked" and "User votes >> User Removed >> Question Closed >> results in shown as Community ♦ voted to close"... :)

Comment: Complicated parts are complicated, @Aditya - if you're interested, ask a separate question and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: Okay... Give me some time and I would try to ask a proper and hopefully sane and sensible question :)

Comment: Very neat, I shouldn't have doubted what the person who wrote the highest voted answer in the history of Stack Overflow said. ;)

Comment: Wait... shouldn't close votes age away over time? If so, was there a bug?

Comment: [Rules for close vote aging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124), @Shadow

Comment: consider [edit]ing to reflect recent change when Community additionally started closing as [approval for asker's decision on dupe close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/165773)

Comment: @gnat I suggested an edit just before you said that! http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38516