# Why does community user vote to close a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508474/adding-two-64-bit-number-using-free-pascal) was closed by community moderator. But according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228455/when-does-the-community-%E2%99%A6-moderator-vote-to-close-a-question) that only happens when the user was deleted before the question was closed, which is not the case. Because he must have gold badge to close the question right away, but in that case his name will be simply unlinked. It's not because the asker deleted his account either. And it's not an [abandoned question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Why does that happen?

Comment: In this case, you raised a dupe flag, and the owner of the question will have confirmed the suggested dupe answered their question. So Community user closed it, just like you have just done here with this question :)

Comment: Funny; what the question asks, happened to the question :D