# What is the result when a diamond Moderator chooses "Leave Open"?

Tags: support, review, moderators

If a diamond Moderator uses the Close Votes review queue and chooses "Leave open", what happens?

- Does their vote count as just one of several that might kick the question out of the queue, or does it get kicked out right away?
- If the question is removed from the queue right away, are all of the other close votes dismissed, or do they stay?

It's clear what happens if the Moderator chooses "Close"; it's a binding close vote, just like if they vote to close from elsewhere. It's less clear what happens if they go the other way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does their vote count as just one of several that might kick the question out of the queue, or does it get kicked out right away?

The question is removed from the queue immediately.

> If the question is removed from the queue right away, are all of the other close votes dismissed, or do they stay?

The close votes stay, but they start [aging away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away).

Comment: Please consider adding this piece of information in the relevant FAQ page that specifically talks about [review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work). Maybe as a separate answer. Thank you.