# How to remove the "possible duplicate" banner? (before the question is actually closed)

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

How could you change a post that is marked as "possible duplicate" (only OP can see the banner) after receiving dupe flags or close votes, but was changed to make it not a duplicate? Can it be changed from a duplicate to not a duplicate by the asker?

The question at [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)  is similar but is not the same. I am asking how to remove the "duplicate" flag, and unless I missed something the answers in the link above do not specify how.

Comment: @brasofilo How did you label this as a possible duplicate?

Comment: Because I think the other question has the answer to what you're asking here...

Comment: **How** did you mark it as a duplicate, not why?

Comment: As I don't have close votes privilege, I used "Flag > Duplicate"

Comment: So that is how it is done. Now how to mark it as not a duplicate when it is marked as one. If you know then you can answer my question.

Comment: @brasofilo Where did you put "Flag > Duplicate"

Comment: @AChildofGod http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts. You need 15 rep to see the flag link.

Comment: I just edited to make it clear how it's different. (At first it wasn't clear so I voted too, luckily my hammer allowed me to achieve double effect here)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wow - it was not clear at all that this is what the OP meant before your edit! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ true, reading the answer made me understand. :-)

Comment: Thanks for rewording my question! I didn't know exactly how to word it to get what I want, but the way it is worded now is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After one person has voted to close as a duplicate or one person has flagged as a duplicate, here is what happens:

- the original poster (only) sees a notice that this might be a duplicate, and can [agree or disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes).
- the post is added to the "close votes" [queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) where other users can vote to close or to leave open

If at any point the post is edited, it is added to the "reopen [queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)" where other users can vote to reopen it. If it is closed as a duplicate before it is edited, high rep users can vote to reopen from the post itself, which will also add it to the reopen queue.

Assuming your edit made it clear that it is not a duplicate, over the next little while either the [close votes will age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away), or enough leave open votes will be left, or (if it was closed) enough reopen votes will be left, that the post will be re-opened if it was closed, or will have the notice (that only the original poster saw) removed. At this point you will have successfully removed the duplicate-ness of the post. It's really a matter of time.