# Find the time left before expiration of votes?

Tags: discussion, support, review, vote-to-close

Trying to reduce the size of the [close vote review queue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (currently at 7.8k), I'm wondering if there is a way to find the time left before votes begin expiring on a post.

There's some scripts that have been created by user in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to search on post with x number of votes and in certain tags, it would be good to be able to include a sort of vote aging.

For info about close vote aging: [How do close votes age away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away)

Comment: The best option that I can see would be to expose the date until the next vote ages away in the API.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm almost wanting to edit this as a feature request. Would you like me too?

Comment: @TinyGiant That's, uhh, not gonna happen. Because that isn't something we calculate or store anywhere since a lot of variables can affect it. Close vote aging occurs once a day and a single script looks through all the votes and determines any that are eligible for aging away in one swoop.

Comment: @animuson can we have the script please :P

Comment: @animuson I knew it was a long shot. What about the age of the newest close vote? That combined with [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/288751) (if it is still correct) should give us the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the post: [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) the following rules apply for close vote aging:

- Start aging votes after 14 days, regardless of view count.
- Allow re-casting votes that've aged away after 14 days

There already exist a kind-of crude tool to know how many close votes there are pending and when aging starts, it is this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432126)

```sql
select pf.postid as [Post Link]
     , min(pf.creationdate) as minimum
     , max(pf.creationdate) as maximum
     , count(*) as [number of flags/votes]
     , max(datediff(d, pf.creationdate, getdate()))
from pendingflags pf
inner join posts p on p.id = pf.postid
where pf.flagtypeid in (13,14)
and pf.creationdate < dateadd(d,-14,getdate())
and p.closeddate is null
group by pf.postid
order by count(*) desc
       , max(datediff(d, pf.creationdate, getdate())) desc
```

Downside of using SEDE is that it only gets refreshed once a week.

I'm not so sure if putting effort into making existing voters more effective is the bast way to conquer that queue. The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is already applying a [strategy](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/236526/tags-that-can-be-cleared-of-votes) to have voters use their votes effectively at least once a week, during an event of an hour. The focus on only a few tags with enough voters [brings down that queue](http://socvr.azurewebsites.net/). The effectiveness of that approach is due to the number of voters, not by the used selection though.

It would be interesting to know if users with the close vote privilege are more likely to use their votes if they know when votes expire. My gut feeling says that they don't care. I would love to have a feature that would change that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is useful to know which post is likely to have their votes expire, but I don't mind if that can be added to the API either. It might be useful for statistical analysis too. As animuson said, it might be technically challenging due to the nature of method of determine aging of votes.

Something that might be more useful in my opinion: what if the script sorts the close vote queue on the expiration of the votes? Or give a score to the likeliness of votes expiring? In that way, the UI can present close votes just as it always did, but then in an order that yields the best results in the end.

Comment: What if the question doesn't warrant closing at all? I'm not against ways to reduce the backlog a bit but I'm really not sure if renewed attention to something that survived for a while should still be on the route to closure, specially if there is a complete chatroom dedicated to closing most of the crap.

Comment: But with enough votes it leaves the queue, right? @rene Then at least we can work on the backlog without losing the effort of all those that have done reviews.

Comment: Only if it gets closed (5 votes) or left open (3 votes)

Comment: Okay, so within no-time, those posts should be gone, right?

Comment: Wait, I have the feeling that whatever I answer next, you'll call victory ...

Comment: No, I am not that positive generally :)

Comment: So I guess, yes, posts that deserve it will be gone from the queue quickly if they get either 5 cv, or 3 LO votes. Do know that the order of the queue is curently based on a combination of new and/or active. Active means: got a vote recently. It doesn't take into account if it is the 1st or 4th though.

Comment: I think we should have multiple sort and filter options for the queue. Some with a dupe hammer in a specific tag might want to filter on single-voted duplicates or something like that. This question might go a lot further than just this single change in the API.